# vb.net usercontrol how to update my property

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I'm writing a usercontrol in VS 2019, however when I set the property *checked=true* in the property window, in a new project Form_load, the value of checked is not updated, the debug window shows false, but the value in property window is true

[image: set checked in property window]

[image: checked is false]

here is my *usercontrol code*

```
Private CheckedValue As Boolean
Public Event CheckedChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler
<Browsable(True),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
Category("Data"),
Description("checked"),
DefaultValue(True),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public Property Checked() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CheckedValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            CheckedValue = value
            RaiseEvent CheckedChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Checked"))
        End Set
    End Property
```

In form the code is :

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Debug.Print(Chao_Switch1.Checked)
    'The Switch display **wrong**
End Sub
```

And if i I set the property in code, the value will be right

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Chao_Switch1.Checked=True
    Debug.Print(Chao_Switch1.Checked)
    'The Switch display **right**
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the designer code reflect the setting of the property?

Comment: The property such as backcolor and forecolor , as long as I change it , in design mode it can be display right now. However when Form load the property (such as backcolor or checked) is those i see in the design mode

Comment: the property (such as backcolor or checked) is not those i see in the design mode

Comment: I feel like you sidestepped my question without answering it one way or another. In `Form1.Designer.vb`, do you see the assignment `Chao_Switch1.Checked = true;`?

Comment: No, I can not see it.

Comment: Interesting. It seems like the form designer hasn't updated that file then. Have you manually edited it?

Comment: But I set DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content, is seems that it is not automatically added to Form1.Designer.vb, why ?

Comment: Remove all the attributes set from your control's designer's code.

Comment: Oh , it is useful! i just remove all the attribute set, and it works !!! Why ?

Answer (score 1):

I know why it happens

set `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` to `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible`

Wrong code:

```
<Browsable(True),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
Category("Data"),
Description("description"),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
```

Right code:

```
<Browsable(True),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
Category("Data"),
Description("description"),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
```

Comment: And Thanks @preciousbetine

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly be the issue. The only difference there is the `Category` value and there's no way that caused this behaviour. I can only assume that removing and adding the attributes caused something to be reset by the compiler or something else that fixed some corruption somewhere.

Comment: That is, unless the order of the attributes matters, but I can't see that being the case.

Comment: set `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` to `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible`

Comment: Ah, OK. Maybe I misread but I don't think you had that originally. Regardless, all's well that ends well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be confused between "default value" and "initial value". That `DefaultValue` attribute is actually telling you what value the property will be set to if you right-click it in the designer and select *Reset*.

Unless you explicitly set it, any property is going to have the default value for its type. Your property is type `Boolean` so its initial value will be `False` unless you set it otherwise. Unless you set the property, it will reflect the initial value of its backing field. You're not initialising the backing field so it will be `False`. If you want the property to be `True` initially then you need to initialise the backing field:

```
Private CheckedValue As Boolean = True
```

Comment: Thanks very much to your answer ! However, i just want to set value by clicking the property window so it can be seen in the design mode, the property such as backcolor and forecolor , as long as I change it , in design mode it can be display right now. However when Form load  the value(such as backcolor or checked) is not the value i see in the design mode

Comment: You are wasting my time and yours. I've told you how to fix your problem. Do it. That has got nothing to do with whether you can change the property value in the designer.

Comment: It sounds to me like something on your system is broken. Fields/properties are not going to spontaneously become `False` when they have been set to `True`. I would suggest that you create a new test project and create a new user control from scratch, making it as simple as possible to reflect the functionality you want. See whether that shows the same unexpected behaviour.